# How do i get a specific value in a multidimensional array using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array like this:

```
  pnotifyArr[] = array( 
    "type" => "New ".$RowP[0]."</br>",
    "title" => "<a href=\"/sys/mailbox/MailInbox.php?ID=$RowP[3]$rid\" onclick=\"javascript:update_status('$RefID')\" target=\"_blank\">".$TitleForShow."</a></br>", 
    "AssignedBy" => "From: ".trim($RowP[2]).".", 
    "RefID"=>$RefID, 
    "Status"=>$Status, 
    "Notice_type" => $TypeN, 
    "Notice_title" => $TitleForShow, 
    "Notice_AssignedBy" => $RowP[2]
  );
```

which is retrieved from the database. But I need only the key values of `Notice_type` and `Notice_title` to be compared in all the instances.

```
if(count($pnotifyArr)>0)
    {
        $rows   = sizeof($pnotifyArr);
        $columns = sizeof($pnotifyArr[0]);
        //$columnkeys = array_key_exists('Notice_type',$pnotifyArr[0]);


        for ($i =0; $i < $columns; $i++)
        {
            for ($j =0; $j < $rows; $j++)
            {
                for($k = $j+1; $k < $rows; $k++)
                {
                    if( $pnotifyArr[$j][$columnkeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$columnkeys[$i]]) //&& ($pnotifyArr[$j][$columnkeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$columnkeys[$i]]) )
                    $pnotifyArr[$k][$columnkeys[$i]] = "";
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I don't know how to get the values of these two specific keys recursively. Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

The above code gets me all the key values any which is not required in my case.

Thanks a lot for spending your time.

```
for ($i =0; $i < $columns; $i++)
        {
            for ($j =0; $j < $rows; $j++)
            {
                for($k = $j+1; $k < $rows; $k++)
                {
                    //if( $pnotifyArr[$j][$typekeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$typekeys[$i]]) && ($pnotifyArr[$j][$titlekeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$titlekeys[$i]]) )
                    if( $pnotifyArr[$j]['Notice_type'] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k]['Notice_type']  && $pnotifyArr[$j]['Notice_title'] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k]['Notice_title'] )

                         $pnotifyArr[$k][$i] = "";


                }
            }
        }
```

My output shows something like this........ as below

```
for ($i =0; $i < $columns; $i++)
        {
            for ($j =0; $j < $rows; $j++)
            {
                for($k = $j+1; $k < $rows; $k++)
                {
                    //if( $pnotifyArr[$j][$typekeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$typekeys[$i]]) && ($pnotifyArr[$j][$titlekeys[$i]] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k][$titlekeys[$i]]) )
                    if( $pnotifyArr[$j]['Notice_type'] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k]['Notice_type']  && $pnotifyArr[$j]['Notice_title'] ==  $pnotifyArr[$k]['Notice_title'] )
                        {
                         $pnotifyArr[$k][$i] = "";
                        }                               
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($pnotifyArr as $key => $value) {
            if ($value="") {
                unset($pnotifyArr[$key]);
            }
        } 
        $pnotifyArr = array_values($pnotifyArr);
```

Please help me.... I dont understand Whats happening here......

Output:

> test:{"pnotify":[
>   {"type":"New Mail</br>","title":"RE: Hello</a></br>","AssignedBy":"From: SAMANTHA CHUA PEIXUAN.","RefID":"1fbc490c47ae00967623bf93f92b9262","Status":"1","Notice_type":"Mail","Notice_title":"RE: Hello","Notice_AssignedBy":"SAMANTHA CHUA PEIXUAN"},
>
> {"type":"New Mail</br>","title":"RE: Hello</a></br>","AssignedBy":"From: SAMANTHA CHUA PEIXUAN.","RefID":"ead077c279a7cfdf60882fcc75a8f23b","Status":"1","Notice_type":"Mail","Notice_title":"RE: Hello","Notice_AssignedBy":"SAMANTHA CHUA PEIXUAN","0":"","1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":"","6":"","7":""}]}

Comment: If you only need those values, select only those values from the DB.

Comment: No i need those values only for checking purpose...

Comment: Anyone help me.... I am dying......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get specific value in looping:

`$pnotifyArr[$j]['Notice_type'];`

`$pnotifyArr[$k]['Notice_title'];`

example:

```
foreach($pnotifyArr as $key=>$val)
{
 if($pnotifyArr[$key]['Notice_type'] == $pnotifyArr[$key]['Notice_title'])
 {
    $pnotifyArr[$key][XXX] = '';
 }
}
```

To Remove Empty Key:

```
foreach($pnotifyArr as $key=>$val)
{
 if($pnotifyArr[$key]['Notice_type'] == $pnotifyArr[$key]['Notice_title'])
 {
    $pnotifyArr[$key][XXX] = '';
 }

 if (is_null($val)) 
 {
   unset($pnotifyArr[$key]);
 } 
}
```

Then try print_r  `print_r($pnotifyArr);`

Comment: It showa error: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\sys\includes\toNotify.php</b> on line <b>235</b><br />

Comment: Edit my answer with sample usage.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/8200464/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-key-in-an-array-using-php....  Can i do this to remove my empty spaces from the array.... how do i do it?

Comment: Yes.. check my answer, added example how to remove empty array

Comment: I need to the array but have to remove only the empty indexes in the array.... give me some solution for that...

Answer (score 1):

function array_uniquecolumn($arr)
        {
            $temp_array = array();
            $temp_array1 = array();
            $final_array = array();

```
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $temp_array[] = $value["Notice_type"].$value["Notice_title"];
        }
        //print_r ($temp_array);

        $temp_array = array_unique($temp_array);
        $temp_array1 = array_keys($temp_array);
        //print_r ($temp_array1);

        foreach ($temp_array1 as $key => $value) {
            $final_array[] = $arr[$value];
        }
        return ($final_array);
    }

    //print_r( array_uniquecolumn($pnotifyArr));
```

I get perfect result from this function......

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($pnotifyArr as $child_array) {
    echo $child_array['Notice_type'];
    echo $child_array['Notice_title'];
}
```

Comment: foreach($pnotifyArr as $child_array)
  {
   $typekeys = $child_array['Notice_type'];;
   $titlekeys = $child_array['Notice_title'];
  }

Comment: What happens if i retrieve this value like this... Will it return an array? &typekeys and $titlekeys are arrays????? help me...

Comment: No if you do that it returns a single value but it will be replaced for each array in the loop, so if you are using those variables in the loop you are golden